# Handle SVN tags in Git (BitBucket)?

Tags: git, svn, bitbucket

We are FINALLY moving from SVN to Git, but have about 40 tagged builds tracking various incarnations of apps that we want to keep around.

I originally made a "tags" repository and imported the SVN tags folder into it, which is fine, but then I realized if I want to pull a specific tag, I need to get ALL of them, which I do not want.

Is there some way to handle this scenario with branches or some other construct in Git?

Thanks for tolerating the noob question as I acclimated to the DVCS world!

Comment: While I don't understand why you'd want a separate repository in the first place, it's not true that you have to fetch all tags. `git fetch` allows you do specify exactly what to fetch, so e.g. `git fetch name-of-remote-url refs/tags/v1.2.3` would work.

Comment: Cheers, Magnus (great name, btw).  The separate repo is an artifact of our current workflow, and part of our learning curve.  Please post your response as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Ack... does not work.  When we imported SVN tags into Git (again, via BitBucket) it created a folder for each tag, which is how it was structured in SVN.  They are not actual Git tags.  Is there a best-practice for doing this?  Or a way to make each folder a Git tag?

Comment: There are other tools for Subversion to Git migrations that handle tags (and branches) properly. I'd expect git-svn to be the canonical choice, but there might be even better choices. I don't see why you'd have to use what Bitbucket provides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out git-svn has the functionality for this, and here are some instructions on how:
http://git-scm.com/book/ch8-2.html